# Handmade paper precoating for inkjet printing

Tags: printing, ink-jet, epson, giclee

I saw a similar question here that was discussed in 2017 so I wondered if there’s any fresh information.

I wonder if someone here is experienced in making homemade covering for different types of paper (handmade, old paper, random paper) for inkjet dye printing (Epson 8550). I live in a country where it’s impossible to get InkAID coating. I know some handmade paper manufacturers produce their own coating but obviously they wouldn’t share a recipe.

I tried (don’t laugh) hairspray, pva glue, gelatine, acrylic covering in different combinations and it didn’t work out. If you could advise at least what to start with, I’d really appreciate it.

Comment: How does the paper accept inkjet printing without a coating? I mean printing on plain uncoated paper is good enough for some uses.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DIY inkjet transparency film or photopaper](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/113579/diy-inkjet-transparency-film-or-photopaper)

Comment: or https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/69098/60903

Comment: I've had good luck with spray clear coat acrylic, made them last as fridge magnets for 20+ years.